# Is there some class which represents a period between two dates like org.joda.time.Period?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a method that must returns a Period between two dates. I thought to use org.joda.time.Period, a nice and stuffed class, but I could not find in this a method that show me which is the first Date and the last Date.

For example, if I create a Period instance like this:

```
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("02/21/2016"));
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("02/22/2016"));

Period result = new Period(fromDate, toDate);
```

How can I figure out wich is the first and the last Date based **only** in the `result` object?

If this class does not allow this, so what class I could use?

Comment: You can't.  A Period is, for example, 3 days.  If I tell you "it took 3 days" how would you know the context (that is, the start and stop days) from that?  You'll need some point of reference, i.e. the "from" or "to" date to know that information.

Comment: You can create your own Java object class that contains an org.joda.time.Period, the first date, and the last date.

Comment: A `Period` is not connected to / anchored on a timeline, so it does not memorize the range limits used in construction. And Joda-Time does not support date intervals at all (only instant intervals) but maybe you are interested in another library - see this [example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/49fa10691baf0318dd04) using Time4J (written by me). Keep also in mind that Joda-Time is in maintenance mode now so there is no hope for any bigger future enhancements like that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the class [`Pair`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html), from Apache Commons...